# How to delete sql logins after database is deleted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A database named 'TestDB', created SQL logins for the database which are present in security -> Users of the server in SSMS.

After a while, I deleted the database but the SQL logins remain. Now i need to revoke the role those newly orphaned users, delete these orphaned user and their login itself.

This process can be done manually but i need a script so that i can delete all the orphan logins of any deleted database. I have 150+ logins to be deleted so writing query to delete each user login manually is not a option. 
Need a generic script which would work.

Query to Revoke Role:

```
exec sp_droprolemember [db_datareader],[LOGIN-NAME];
```

Query to Drop User:

```
Drop User USER-NAME
```

Query to Drop Login:

```
Drop Login USER-NAME
```

Comment: Little confused by your statement of needing to drop users from a deleted database. User's are a database object; if you delete the database the user will be as well. The login will still exist, however, it won't be orphaned; an orphaned user is when a (database) user doesn't have a Server Login. Are you, therefore, looking to delete **logins** that don't have any respective users on any user databases? Are there any specific Server Roles we need to leave as is (i.e. your sys admins are unlikely to have a user on a database, due to being a sysadmin).

Comment: Users are a database object. *Logins* are a server object. If you can't even login, you can't use a database after all. A login can access multiple databases so it doesn't make sense to delete it if only one of them is deleted. If you want the users/logins to be part of a single database, you need to create a [Contained Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases)

Comment: @larnu: yes, I am looking to delete logins that do not have any respective users on any user databases. Server Roles like datareader and datawriter are to be left as is.

Comment: "Server Role Datareader"??? `db_datareader` is a database role (there's a hint there in the prefix), not a server role. Do you also have a server role `datareader` and `datawriter`? What other roles should we be ignoring?